# MySQL - SQL Statement Works But Fails to Create VIEW

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

When I run this SQL in Workbench, it produces the desired output: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4ofodxtwslz228i/Screenshot%202018-01-02%2003.34.25.png?dl=0

However, when I attempt to create a view, the following error results:
*Unknown column 'LEAD(`latest_20`.`session_date`) OVER (PARTITION BY `latest_20`.`level` ORDER BY `latest_20`.`session_date` DESC, `level` ASC)' in 'field list'*

What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT
*, 
CONCAT(
    `lead_table`.`Session_Count`, ', ',
    DATE_FORMAT(`lead_table`.`Session_Date`, '%c/%e/%Y'), ', ',
    DATE_FORMAT(`lead_table`.`Session_Date`, '%l:%i %p'), ', ',
    if(Timestampdiff(DAY, `lead_table`.`lead`, `lead_table`.`Session_Date`) is null, 'na', Timestampdiff(DAY, `lead_table`.`lead`, `lead_table`.`Session_Date`)), ', ',
    if(Mod(Timestampdiff(hour, `lead_table`.`lead`, `lead_table`.`Session_Date`), 24) is null, 'na', Mod(Timestampdiff(hour, `lead_table`.`lead`, `lead_table`.`Session_Date`), 24)), ', ',
    if(Mod(Timestampdiff(MINUTE, `lead_table`.`lead`, `lead_table`.`Session_Date`), 60) is null, 'na', Mod(Timestampdiff(MINUTE, `lead_table`.`lead`, `lead_table`.`Session_Date`), 60))
) AS comb_label

FROM
(
  SELECT
     *,
     LEAD(`latest_20`.`session_date`) OVER (PARTITION BY `latest_20`.`level` ORDER BY `latest_20`.`session_date` DESC, `level` ASC) AS lead,
     Dayname(Lead(`latest_20`.`session_date`) OVER (PARTITION BY `latest_20`.`level` ORDER BY `latest_20`.`session_date` DESC, `level` ASC)) AS lead_day 
  FROM
     (
        SELECT
           * 
        FROM
           view_performance_accuracy_pct 
        WHERE
           user_id = 1 AND `level` = 'Basic' 
        ORDER BY
           session_date DESC,
           `level` ASC LIMIT 20
    ) AS latest_20 
  ORDER BY latest_20.session_date ASC
) AS lead_table
```

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: I am running MariaDB 10.2 which is capable of executing several window functions.  The SELECT works, the CREATE a VIEW won't.

Comment: It appears that if I remove the "Dayname()..." statement, a VIEW can be created.  I have no idea why.

Comment: Is "view_performance_accuracy_pct" a table or a view? Maybe there is a limitation to create VIEW on the top of a VIEW

Comment: @twyly, it's a VIEW.  With regard to a view not being able to access another view, I don't believe there is one--I've been able to do that numerous times.  Thank you for asking.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "SELECT *," please specify all column names individually.
For example

> SELECT col1, col2, ... FROM

Comment: What's the logic behind this ? Is it resolved the issue ??

Comment: It look like MySQL VIEW can't find the real column name to build a correct view.

Comment: `*` means all the columns which comes from table and every column has it's name so it's should not be the case.

Comment: @Susang, you are correct.  Specifying the column names does nothing to resolve the issue.